# How can Python's `assert False` prevent pytest from working?

Tags: python, import, assert

I've added an `assert False` statement in [flask/helpers.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/helpers.py#L866) in the following class's `__init__` method:

```
class locked_cached_property(object):
    """A decorator that converts a function into a lazy property.  The
    function wrapped is called the first time to retrieve the result
    and then that calculated result is used the next time you access
    the value.  Works like the one in Werkzeug but has a lock for
    thread safety.
    """

    def __init__(self, func, name=None, doc=None):

        assert False
        # ^ this is the problem

        self.__name__ = name or func.__name__
        self.__module__ = func.__module__
        self.__doc__ = doc or func.__doc__
        self.func = func
        self.lock = RLock()

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        with self.lock:
            value = obj.__dict__.get(self.__name__, _missing)
            if value is _missing:
                value = self.func(obj)
                obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = value
            return value
```

and now when I'm running `pytest` I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/code/virtualenv/project_a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 381, in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
KeyError: local('~/code/flask/tests')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/code/virtualenv/project_a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 412, in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[conftestpath]
KeyError: local('~/code/flask/tests/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/code/virtualenv/project_a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 418, in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
  File "~/code/virtualenv/project_a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 668, in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "~/code/virtualenv/project_a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 290, in load_module
    six.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
  File "~/code/flask/tests/conftest.py", line 19, in <module>
    import flask
  File "~/code/flask/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "~/code/flask/flask/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import cli, json
  File "~/code/flask/flask/cli.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .helpers import get_debug_flag, get_env, get_load_dotenv
  File "~/code/flask/flask/helpers.py", line 894, in <module>
    class _PackageBoundObject(object):
  File "~/code/flask/flask/helpers.py", line 956, in _PackageBoundObject
    @locked_cached_property
  File "~/code/flask/flask/helpers.py", line 876, in __init__
    assert False
AssertionError
ERROR: could not load ~/code/flask/tests/conftest.py
```

I'm curious how an `assert False` statement can seem to cause an import failure when in the `__init__` function.  If the `assert False` was in the `__get__` function I am still able to import the module.

This occurs for pytest 3.8.1 and 4.0.2.

Does this mean that a decorator's `__init__` is called during the importing of the module?

Comment: The traceback tells you exactly how.  Read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorator will always raise an exception when being used. And remember that the decorator code is executed right after the `def` line it decorates. So, in most cases the module can not be imported without an exception. Since `pytest` imports a module first it will never get to the point where it executes the tests.

Comment: I didn't ask this well enough in the original question.  So does that mean the decorator / class's __init__ is called during the importing of the module?  If I put the `assert False` in the `__get__` method I can still import the module.

Comment: How can I tell which code gets called during a modules import process?

Comment: You have not shown hiw you areusing the decorator. But the expression after the `@` must not raise an exception. What happens later when the decorated function is called will not disturb the input, except the function is somehow called at import of cause.

Comment: @NateW All of the module code is executed in the module global namespace. Just follow the usual execution rules.

Comment: In general all lines at the top indentation level are executed. Also the second level in `class` definitions is executed. This extends to classes inside of classes. Code inside of a `def` block is not executed. Of cause top level code can call a function and execute its code anyway. The same applies to methods in classes especially the  constructor.

Comment: @KlausD. your explanation helped me out a lot.  Top level code was calling the `__init__`.  That completely makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you defined a function or class, python interpreter executed the decorator.

Then, it hit your assert line and raise an exception

Comment: So a decorator / class's __init__ is called during the importing of the module?  If I put the `assert False` in the `__get__` method I can import the module.

Comment: @NateW Is the decorator actually used somewhere? Then `__init__` will be obviously called.

Comment: @NateW yes, you can try it by yourself

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut @ChienNguyen How can I tell which types of functions/methods will be called during the import process?  I'm assuming that's what is happening, right?  Getting this from `__import__(modname)`.

Comment: @ChienNguyen yeah